# How to tar the n most recent files with spaces in filename?

Tags: bash, tar

I am trying to create a script that foreach directoy in the `folder` folder, only the `n` most recent files are to be compressed.

However, I am having trouble with the multiple word files. I need a way to wrap them in quote marks so the `tar` command knows wich is each file.

Here is my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d ~/backup ]; then
    mkdir ~/backup
fi

cd ~/folder
for i in *; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        original=`pwd`
        cd $i
        echo tar zcf ~/backup/"$i".tar.gz "`ls -t | head -10`"
        cd $original
    fi
done
echo "Backup copied in $HOME/backup/"
exit 0
```

Comment: Do this error out? BTW, never parse the output of ls!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xargs` to the rescue! One way is to use xargs to create argument list but put each file inside of quotes:

```
echo `ls -t1 | head -10 | xargs -I'{}' echo \"{}\"`
```

Other option it to use `xargs` to directly call `tar` in append mode (`-r`) and then compressing it at the end (you cannot create compressed archives in append mode):

```
ls -t | head -10 | xargs -I'{}' tar -rvf ~/backup/"$i".tar '{}'
gzip ~/backup/"$i".tar
```

The advantage of the 2nd approach is that you can change `10` to any other, even very high number and it will still work without getting too long argument list.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $backup = $ENV{HOME} . '/backup';
my $folder = $ENV{HOME} . '/folder';

-d $backup or mkdir $backup or die $!;
chdir $folder or die $!;
while (my $node = glob '*') {
    if (-d $node) {
        chdir $node;
        my @files = sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } glob '*';  # Sort files by age.
        @files = @files[0 .. 9] if @files > 10;         # Keep only the newest 10.
        system 'tar', 'zcf', "$backup/$node.tar.gz", @files;
        chdir '..';
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a bash question though. I need to do it in bash.

Comment: @dabadaba: Always use the right tool for a job *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d $HOME/backup ]; then
    mkdir $HOME/backup
fi

cd $HOME/folder
for i in *; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        tar -cf $HOME/backup/"$i".tar -T /dev/null #create an empty, uncompressed, archive
        cd "$i"
        ls -t | head -10 | while read file; do
            tar -rf $HOME/backup/"$i".tar "$file" #append $file to archive
        done
        gzip $HOME/backup/"$i".tar # compress the archive
        cd $OLDPWD
    fi
done
echo "Backup copied in $HOME/backup/"
exit 0
```

Comment: @dabadaba OK, you should realize this from when I add my answer... I didn't used double double quotes in my answer ;) Now you can clean your comments, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
n=3
shopt -s nullglob
for dir in */; do
    cd "$dir"
    files=(*)
    if (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )); then
        files=()
        while IFS= read -r filename; do
            files+=("$filename")
        done < <( stat -c "%Y %n" * | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2- | head -n $n )
        tar cf ../"${dir%/}.tar" "${files[@]}"
    fi
    cd - &>/dev/null
done
```